# Haunted curse interaction with ammunition

Tags: pathfinder-1e

An Oracle with the [haunted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses#TOC-Haunted) curse wants to use a bow (and is proficient with it).  Does the act of drawing an arrow require the character to draw an arrow as a standard action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, Provided you're drawing it from a quiver**

Haunted:

> Retrieving any stored item from your gear requires a standard action,
>   unless it would normally take longer.

When it is talking about stored gear, it's referring to things in your pack, like potions/books/torches/bedroll/whatever. "Retrieve a stored item" is usually a move action that provokes an AoO, and the Haunted curse makes it worse.

Further, Drawing/Nocking an arrow is covered by another action type:

Drawing an arrow (from the combat section):

> **Not an Action**
>
> Some activities are so minor that they are not even considered free
>   actions. They literally don't take any time at all to do and are
>   considered an inherent part of doing something else, such as nocking
>   an arrow as part of an attack with a bow.

Comment: Thanks, solid answer and you managed to answer it after the game started, but before first combat.

Comment: Glad I could help!